# React API call failure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to build (for now) a simple app that allows you to search for a name in a list of transactions and return the transaction details to you. So far I have been struggling to deal with the API request and I keep running into errors. I'm using superagent for my API calls

```
    import React, {Component } from 'react';
    import Request from 'superagent'
    import './App.css';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        var url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/2dorw';

        Request.get(url).then((response) => {
          this.setState({
            items: response.body.items,
          });
        });
      }

      render() {
        var names = this.state.items.map((name, index) => {
            <div>
                <li key={index}> {this.state.items.merchant.name } </li>
            </div>
        });

        return ( 
            <div className="App">
                {names}
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

I can't even make this simple API call to work, just display the names from the API endpoint. This has been going on for a day or so, and usually I get the object either null, undefined and type errors.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null(…)

App.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I have tried following tutorials but I haven't been able to find one that would work in my case, so I can't wrap my head around the API call.

**UPDATE**

After changing to componentDidMount(), adding isFetching and setting items to an array in setState (as the two answers have suggested), I am now getting an

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `componentWillMount()` is slightly early in the lifecycle.  Wait until it has mounted using `componentDidMount()` That should help resolve the first error being thrown.

The second error comes from `this.state.items.map`  when the `items` have not shown up yet.  I would also suggest adding a `isFetching` state, to check if the data has shown up yet.:

```
 class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isFetching: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/2dorw';
    Request.get(url).then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        items: response.body.items,
        isFetching: false
      });  
    });
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.isFetching) return null;

    var names = this.state.items.map((item, index) => { 
      <div>
        <li key={index}> {item.merchant.name} </li>
      </div >
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {names}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### Update

Added a slight change - looks like your map function was also a bit off.  It's hard to say what exactly you are looking for, because I don't know the data structure exactly.

You had

```
var names = this.state.items.map((name, index) => {
    <div>
        <li key={index}> {this.state.items.merchant.name } </li>
    </div>
});
```

Passing `name` as the first param, which is the entire item.  You then call this.state all over again - which you shouldn't need to do.  I think this is where some of the `undefined` issues are coming from as well.

Comment: Tried the above but it just gives me another error.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Most of my errors are tied to the "undefined" that keeps popping up.

Comment: Ok - I updated - without the actual data structure of `items` it's hard to say what the actual code should be - but hoping this helps. @Wink207

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.items` is undefined because you declared `state = {}`, so can not map over it. You can fix this problem by making items an empty array.

```
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
      }
```

Comment: Right. This would be the other way to resolve it. Probably will depend on what the goal is there, whether rendering something vs empty is more important.

Comment: Yes it depends on what one wants to achieve :)

Comment: Though its an anti pattern to not defining what items will look like in the state

Comment: I and a bunch of our devs encountered this over and over again - not initializing some state properly or otherwise dealing with race conditions related to lifecycle methods, async data fetches, etc. - so I ultimately decided to create a lib that simplifies a lot of this for many use cases: https://github.com/DigitalGlobe/jetset